# Setup Delivery Module in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

I would like to know..., what is the Module name [image]for magento admin panel, that support with DHL, UPS, Fedex and other international Courrier?

The Free One :)

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The native module `Mage_Usa` (*app/code/core/Mage/Usa*) add these carriers.

*app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml*

```
            <shipping>
                <carriers>
                    <ups>
                        <class>Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups</class>
                    </ups>
                    <usps>
                        <class>Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps</class>
                    </usps>
                    <fedex>
                        <class>Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex</class>
                    </fedex>
                    <dhl>
                        <class>Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Dhl</class>
                    </dhl>
                    <dhlint>
                        <class>Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Dhl_International</class>
                    </dhlint>
                </carriers>
            </shipping>
```